# Firebase with viewpager

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager, fragment, android-animation

I am currently building an app using firebase.
I have an activity in which the background and UI are the same, but the page has only the contents that change inside according to the date.
It`s kind of some diary app.

I am worried about whether I need to ViewPager or not to use ViewPager, but if I have saved it somewhere and clicked on that date, I need to display the contents with setText(). I'm not sure about that how to do more optimization.

And when I scroll horizontally across the screen, I want to see the pages change with swipe-animation. Do I have to use viewPager? I mean I use one page but I want to give a fake animation effect as the page looks. If this helps optimally.

Anyway, So I'm looking for an example that uses viewPager with firebase recycler-view, but it's a bit hard to find. Is it better to use a fragment? with this?

Optimization has been troubling for weeks on issues.
I have a lot of questions, but I would like to hear good advice on these things. 
I would appreciate it if you could explain it slowly and easily.
Thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Page has only the contents that change inside according to the date.It`s kind of some diary app. I am worried about whether I need to
>   ViewPager or not to use ViewPager?

Yes, Viewpager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter is a good choice here, as there may be many dates in your case with its own content.

Check out the below link, it explained very well how any why to use viewpager with tabLayout.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

> And when I scroll horizontally across the screen, I want to see the
>   pages change with swipe-animation. Do I have to use viewPager?

For animation between the page swipes, you can use pageTransformer.

Checkout this

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

and

https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4

Comment: Thanks, Ritesh!  So you're saying that the FragmentStatePagerAdapter helps with optimization, even if there are a lot of these pages? Even only when the text changes? What I mean is that if you use ViewPager, there will be a lot of pages. Does it have anything to do with the badness of optimization?

Comment: yeah, that actually depends on what screenoffsetLimit() you calling on viewpager, by default it is set to 1 and will keep at max 3 pages and the memory and will take care of creating and re-using of it's own. Do read about the same in the provided link.

Comment: In your case, this would be a better choice in terms of memory optimization and as well as the functionality what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Do I have to use RecyclerView with this?

Comment: If you have a list  of data for each date then yes you need to implement recyclerview.